# ClipTo with Image and Background Image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to clip an image with another image into a fabric canvas with background, I try to follow the example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/w396uhnv/)**.

But when I add `backgroundColor` in the first lines the clipping doesn't work any more:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('divPad', {
    width: $("#divPad").width(),
    height: $("#divPad").height(),
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
});
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot work.
You are not clipping but playing with global composite operation in "soruce-atop" mode.
This means that your image will be drawn just on part of canvas where the is something different from transparent.

If you put a solid color as a background this cannot work anymore.

One solution could be having a div under the canvas and make the div yellow and not the canvas itself.

Or you could try to obtain a shape of your image and do some real clipping instead of global compositing.